# How can I format a book to this layout?

Tags: formatting

I want to format a document to the layout of the picture. [image]

How can I format?

Comment: When you say format your document, you mean for the ToC only or also for the text after? And in that case what kind of layout do you wish to have?

Answer (score 1):

Introducing a new sectioning command `lesson` and a little "hacking" should adress the problem:

```
\documentclass{book}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{lesson}
\@addtoreset{section}{lesson}
\def\thechapter{\@arabic\c@chapter.}
\def\thelesson{\@arabic\c@lesson.}
\def\thesection{\MakeUppercase{\@roman\c@section}.}
\def\thesubsection{\@arabic\c@subsection.}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
      \fi
    \fi
  }}
\newcommand\lesson{\@startsection{lesson}{1}{\z@}%
                                 {-3.5ex plus -1ex minus -.2ex}%
                                 {2.3ex plus .2ex}%
                                 {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
\renewcommand*{\@seccntformat}[1]{\csname additional@#1\endcsname \csname the#1\endcsname\quad}
\def\additional@lesson{\S\space}
\newcommand*\l@lesson{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}}
\def\lessonmark#1{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test chapter}
\lesson{The title of the lesson 1}
\section{Section one}
\subsection{Here is a subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\section{Section two}
\lesson{The title of the lesson 2}
\section{Section one}
\subsection{Here is a subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\section{Section two}
\end{document}
```

Comment: When I typeset '\tableofcontents', It doesn't work.

Comment: When I testet the document with a toc like: `...\begin{document}\tableofcontents\chapter{Test chapter}...` it did compile without errors and the toc was printed completely. What exactly did not work on your machine? Did you try compiling the code twice?